# C/C++ Warning: address of temporary with BDADDR_ANY Bluetooth library

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, bluetooth, temporary

I'm having some problems with g++ and the compiling process for a C/C++ program which use Bluetooth libraries under Ubuntu.

If i use gcc, it works fine with no warning; on the contrary, if i use g++ i get this warning:

> warning: taking address of temporary

even if the program compiles fine and it works.

The involved lines reporting the error are:

```
        bdaddr_t *inquiry(){
       // do some stuff.. 
    bacpy(&result[mote++], BDADDR_ANY);
    return result;
}
//...
void zeemote(){
while (bacmp(bdaddr, BDADDR_ANY)){
/..
}
}
```

In both the cases, BDADDR_ANY is involved.

How can i solve this warning?

BDADDR_ANY is defined in bluetooth.h like:

```
/* BD Address */
typedef struct {
    uint8_t b[6];
} __attribute__((packed)) bdaddr_t;

#define BDADDR_ANY   (&(bdaddr_t) {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(&(bdaddr_t) {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}})
```

Constructs a temporary object and uses its address. This isn't allowed in C++.

You can fix this by creating a named temporary variable and using `bacpy` and `bacmp` on it:

```
bdaddr_t tmp = { };

bacpy(&result[mote++], &tmp);
```

and

```
while (bacmp(bdaddr, &tmp)) {
    //
}
```

Comment: How can i fix this? 
I'm not a c++ expert programmer :(

Comment: @MarcusBarnet create a named variable and use `bacpy` on it

Comment: thanks for the answer! but i have to modify the bluetooth.h file or i have to modify only my program?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet good job on paying attention to warnings, most people ignore them at their own peril since they don't stop the program from compiling.

Comment: i'm not an expert programmer, but i'd like to solve all the little "invisible" problems because they can be very dangerous sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable (in whatever scope's convenient) rather than a temporary...

```
bdaddr_t my_bdaddr_any = { 0 };
while (bacmp(bdaddr, my_bdaddr_any))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the bluetooth.h file you will see you can simply do this yourself in C++ by just going

```
bdaddr_t bdaddr_any =  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

sockaddr_rc server;
server.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
server.rc_bdaddr = bdaddr_any;
server.rc_channel = (uint8_t)1;
```

Comment: Best  KISS answer ,